# In Java, why is my multithreading not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, applet, graphics2d

At first I did this:

```
public SpaceCanvas(){
    new Thread(new Runnable () {//this is the thread that triggers updates, no kidding
        int fcount = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
                System.out.println("Update thread started!");
                while(!Thread.interrupted()){
                    fcount++;
                    while(players.iterator().hasNext()){
                        players.iterator().next().update(fcount);
                    }
                    while(entities.iterator().hasNext()){
                        entities.iterator().next().update(fcount);
                    }
                    System.out.println("About to paint");
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println("Done with paints");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }).start();
    players.add(new LocalPlayer(0, 9001, 0, 0, 0, 0, this, null));
}
```

in the initializer of a thing I call a SpaceCanvas.
However, that doesn't allow the canvas, and therefore the applet it is within, to be created, because the Thread doesn't *actually* run asynchronously. Then, I replaced ".start()" with ".run()" and the thread only ran once, but the SpaceCanvas initialized perfectly.

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this sort of code works the way you expect it to:

```
while(players.iterator().hasNext()){
    players.iterator().next().update(fcount);
```

`players.iterator()` gets a new iterator for the `players` collection.  If there are 0 items in the collection then it will be `false` but if there are any items, you will be in an infinite loop, creating a new iterator each time.  The `iterator()` call inside of `players` generates another new iterator object as well.

I think you should doing something like:

```
Iterator iterator = players.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next().update(fcount);
}
```

This is the same with your `entities` loop as well.  A better pattern (as of Java 5) is to use the `for` loop:

```
for (Player player : players) {
    player.update(fcount);
}
```

Also, if multiple threads are accessing these collections, they have to be somehow `synchronized`.  You can either use a concurrent collection or you have to make sure *every* access (read and write) is within a `synchronized` block.

```
synchronized (players) {
    for (Player player : players) {
        player.update(fcount);
    }
}
...
// down in the outer thread
synchronized (players) {
    players.add(new LocalPlayer(0, 9001, 0, 0, 0, 0, this, null));
}
```

Obviously the `entities` will need to be `synchronized` in the same manner.

Comment: You could also use `for (Iterator<Player> i = players.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) i.next().update(fcount);`

Answer (score 1):

1. In this millennium, use Swing (`JApplet/JPanel`) rather than AWT (`Applet/Canvas`)
2. When using Swing, establish a Swing `Timer` that calls `repaint()` every 500 msec.
3. (When using Swing/`Timer`) Don't call `Thread.sleep(n)` on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

---

> ..can you draw on a JPanel?

Sure thing.  To do so, override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  You might also extend a `JComponent` and do the same, but there are some quirks to dealing with a `JComponent` that make the `JPanel` the better choice to extend.

On the other hand, there is another approach entirely.

- Create a `BufferedImage` of the size required for whatever custom graphic is needed.
- Add the image to an `ImageIcon`.
- Add the icon to a `JLabel`.
- Add the label to the GUI.
- On each `Timer` action.

  - Call `image.getGraphics()` to obtain the drawing surface.
  - Replicate what you might have done in `paint()` or `paintComponent()`

    1. (If needed) erase all previous drawing.
    2. Draw the current custom rendering.
  - `dispose()` of the `Graphics` instance of the image.
  - call `label.repaint()`

Comment: I'll try this soon, thanks.
Also, can you draw on a JPanel? Can you Draw on any Swing anything? I want to use a Canvas so I can draw on it.

Comment: This is really, really useful, (even if it didn't solve my question) so thanks for keeping me within the coding standards of the millenium!